# Change Tab Size In QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtabwidget

I recently learned about QTabWidget and tried using it in python. My question is, can I change the height, width and background of each individual tab?

I tried doing

```
self.Tab1.setStyleSheet("background: white")
```

but that did nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use:

```
{your QTabWidget}.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab { height: 100px; width: 100px; background: 'red'}")
```